# quicksort algorithm - partition which only needs n-1 comparisons. How can I achieve this?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, quicksort, partition

> "We have seen that partition() performs n comparisons (possibly n−1 or
> n+1, depending on the implementation)."

source: [http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~leon/cs-mcs401-r07/handouts/quicksort-continued.pdf](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Eleon/cs-mcs401-r07/handouts/quicksort-continued.pdf)

If I take a sequence like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 (8 as pivot element, n = 8)
I think I have at least 8 comparisons and not 7 (n-1)

If I move from left to right to find an element which is greater 8

1. 1 < 8
2. 2 < 8
3. 3 < 8
4. 4 < 8
5. 5 < 8
6. 6 < 8
7. 7 < 8

At least one comparison more to check if I find an element which is smaller 8 /to check if indizes are croessed.
8. i < j

Which Implementation of the partition would only need n-1 comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

n-1 comparisons occur when the pivot is never moved and never compared with itself, such as  Lomuto partition scheme.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme

Hoare partition scheme does more compares but typically it does fewer swaps than Lomuto.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

In my benchmarks, I found Lomuto to be slightly faster for pseudo-random data with very few duplicates. If the number of duplicates is significant, Hoare is faster, and in the case of all equal elements, it's Lomuto's worst case O(n^2) and Hoare's best case O(n log2(n)).

Comment: Do they both have O(nlgn) time complexity on average?

Comment: @dwschrute - If the average partition split is almost always at least some ratio, such as 75% | 25%, then time complexity is O(n log(n)). If most of the partition splits are linear, such as n-k | k , then it's approaching O(n^2). It depends on pivot choice and data patterns. Most libraries use some form of [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), monitoring recursion depth and if it gets too deep, switch to heap sort so that worst case time complexity is O(n log(n)). Tracking recursion depth will add some overhead, but that is a constant time factor.